# Word shuffling and comparison with second string

Tags: bash

Shuffle an word randomly and compare with another input string  in case matches found ,return in boolean value.How may I accomplish using bash shell scripting?

For example,

```
Word "cat" ,shuffle like "cta","atc" and so on ... second input string suppose "tac" in case if matches with any of the random shuffle string return in boolean .Like an anagram.
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail that that.  How about examples?

Comment: Thank you so much ....e.g. Word "cat" ,shuffle like "cta","atc" and so on ... second input string suppose "tac" in case if matches with any of the random shuffle string return in boolean.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find if input word 1 is an anagram of input word 2?

Comment: Yes if word 1 is an anagram of second srting

Answer (score 0):

Check for your needed requirement here

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-sequence-of-words-print-all-anagrams-together/